# Automatically reading values off a line graph in R

Tags: r, linegraph

I have a line graph which I have generated in R from a dataset, but I'd now like to be able to read-off the Discharge values at each hour so I can add these to another dataset for later use.

[image: Hydrograph: PlotSyntheticUnitHydrograph(1.606,0.6509467,4.04712)]

As you can see, there are only 3 values in the graph for discharge (Y-axis): 0, 1.606, 0.

The X-axis values correspond to the given Y-axis values: 0, 0.65 and 0.

I now need to get the **Y-axis** values for hours 0, 1, 2, 3, 4 (approx. 0, 1.4, 0.97, 0.48, 0), and automatically generate a list of the values.

I am using my custom function to generate the graph:

```
PlotSyntheticUnitHydrograph <- function(Qp,Tp,Tb) {

  dataPlotsX <- c(0,Tp,Tb)
  dataPlotsY <- c(0,Qp,0)

  yRange <- range(0,(c(0,Qp)))

  plot(dataPlotsX,dataPlotsY, type="o", col="blue", ylim=yRange, ann=FALSE)
  title(xlab="Time (hours)", col.lab="blue")
  title(ylab="Discharge (m^3/s per 10mm)", col.lab="blue")

}
```

**R code to run function to generate this graph**

```
PlotSyntheticUnitHydrograph(1.606,0.6509467,4.04712,5)
```

**For reference:**

- Qp = Peak Discharge (the Y-axis peak on the graph)
- Tp = Time to Peak Discharge
- Tb = Base time; time taken to reduce from peak discharge to 0 (4.04
  hours in this case)

Is this possible to do within R?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not clear that the plot itself has anything to do with this question.  Rather, you have a function defined on a couple of points, and you would like to interpolate its value.  For that, there is a function `approx` that will take the original function and return the linear interpolated value over a set of points.

```
x <- c(0, .6509467, 4.04712)
y <- c(0, 1.606, 0)
```

Then we can do

```
> approx(x, y, 1:4)
$x
[1] 1 2 3 4

$y
[1] 1.44093787 0.96805270 0.49516752 0.02228235
```

Comment: Excellent! That's exactly what I needed. Thank you so much!

Sorry if I over-complicated with the plot, I just wanted to ensure that people had a good context of what I was on about!